# how can i fix Android BootStrap Button Click issue?

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap

I have some issues using a BootStrapButton onclickListener.  Here is my code. When I run the app it crashes.

```
BootstrapButton btn2=(BootstrapButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent nextscreen=new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),Mellipage.class);
        startActivity(nextscreen);

    }
});
```

If anyone knows how I can fix it, please share.

Comment: What is the crash??? Do you get an exception? What happens?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton

01-25 22:41:08.982: E/AndroidRuntime(1741): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton

01-25 22:41:08.982: E/AndroidRuntime(1741):  at com.example.viewpager.FirstFragMent.onCreateView(FirstFragMent.java:24)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by adding this code my problem solved!

```
<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:text="Success"
bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_right="fa-android"
bootstrapbutton:bb_type="success" />
```

Answer (score 2):

From your log:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
```

you have probably declared your button in your layout as a Button instead of BootstrapButton

Change this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```

to

```
<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Success"
    bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_right="fa-android"
    bootstrapbutton:bb_type="success" />
```